# Voronin's universality theorem and the Riemann hypothesis

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

I've recently read about Voronin's universality theorem (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_universality). It is said that this result extends to other kinds of zeta functions.
Now I'm wondering if this universality property is in any way related to the Riemann hypothesis. What I would like to know is this:
Is there an example of a zeta function which is universal in the above sense, but which fails to satsify the generalized Riemann hypothesis, meaning that it has zeros outside of the critical line?

Thanks everyone

Comment: it depends on what you mean by a zeta function; the Davenport Heilbronn function satisfies strong universality (approximates all holomorphic functions like zeta including vanishing ones) and has tons of zeroes in the critical strip, the derivative of zeta or of any $L$ function for Dirichlet characters) satisfies strong universality etc; you should look in Bagchi's paper from 1982 which gives a sort of survey/extension of universality results https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01161980

Comment: Thanks you for this comment. Looks promising